# Problems after trying to alter resolution with xrandr

Tags: monitor, xrandr, teamviewer

I mostly use teamviewer to access my server machine using Ubuntu 16.04 lts. (I'm still learning to use ssh). However since it isn't plugged in to a display teamviewer tends to revert its resolution to a fairly low one.

So i tried to alter the resolution to my prefered one using command "xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1920x1080".

The result was that teamviewer display froze and eventually disconnected. I can't reconnect, teamviewer gets stuck at initializing display parameters.

Now whenever I type "xrandr" i only get "Can't open display".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So a reboot helped.

Reason I didn't try it before posting was because friends were using the VOIP-server.

Anyways, I'm leaving this here in case someone else screws up like I did :)